# how to add scroll to an image view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

Please sugest how to add a scroll to an image view iam writing some message using mouse and saving as image i need a scroll to write bix text in image view ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SEE this Example....And implement this..

```
UIImageView *imgViewCell = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 46.0f, 320.0f, 116.0f)];
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"detail_bg" ofType:@"png"];
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
[imgViewCell setImage:img];
[ScroollView addSubview:imgViewCell];
[img release];
```

Comment: hi deepesh i am drawig in the image view if i put scroll view  i am unable to draw u hav any idea for this please do need ful help

Comment: i think u use padeViewController

Comment: hii padeview controller i dnt know about this can u share sample code

Answer (score 1):

Please download sample code from [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Scrolling/Introduction/Intro.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008023)

This will definitely help you.

Comment: after dng this process i am unable to write on image view how to resolve this i need to wrote some text with mouse in image view and ineed to scroll i have more text to write please do needful help